# Difference between 'Spider-Man' Movie and 'The Amazing Spider-Man' Movie

Tags: the-amazing-spider-man, spider-man, reboot

What is the main differences between the first 'Spider-Man' Movie directed by Sam Raimi and 'The Amazing Spider-Man' by Marc Webb? And why there was a need to reboot a franchise which had a trilogy so recently?

Comment: Why reboot? Did you **see** part 3? OUCH! They jumped like, six or seven sharks there!

Comment: It should also be added that the first question here is off topic as it is basically asking for a list. You could get this quite easily by [googling](http://www.comicbookmovie.com/fansites/JoshWildingNewsAndReviews/news/?a=63086)

Comment: @AndrewMartin Finite lists, like comparisons, aren't off topic.  It's the open-ended list questions that don't work on SE sites, and are off topic.

Comment: @Keen: I'll bear that in mind. I always felt questions about differences were, but I _have_ seen them answered. Thanks for clarification.